# SDL2 in CDT wont build the test program

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw, sdl-2

So, I'm trying to install SDL2 in Eclipse for C++ using MinGW, but I cant get the test program from [the tutorial by Cave of Programming](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/c-for-complete-beginners/setting-up-sdl-windows.html) to build. I've put all the files the tutorial said to into their respective locations. I'm using version 2.0.5 of SDL.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqH5X.jpg) are my eclipse settings.

The build error log:

```
20:42:34 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project sdl
**** Info: Internal Builder is used for build g++ "-IC:\\MinGW\\include\\SDL2" "-includeC:\\MinGW\\include\\SDL2\\SDL.h"
-O2 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\sdl.o" "..\\src\\sdl.cpp" g++ "-LC:\\MinGW\\lib" -shared -o libsdl.exe "src\\sdl.o" -lmingw32
-lSDL2main -lSDL2 src\sdl.o: In function `SDL_main': D:\c++\sdl\sdl\Debug/../src/sdl.cpp:7: undefined reference to `SDL_Init' D:\c++\sdl\sdl\Debug/../src/sdl.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow' D:\c++\sdl\sdl\Debug/../src/sdl.cpp:19: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay' D:\c++\sdl\sdl\Debug/../src/sdl.cpp:22: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow' D:\c++\sdl\sdl\Debug/../src/sdl.cpp:23: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The test program:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Start SDL2
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    // Create a Window in the middle of the screen
    SDL_Window *window = 0;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              640, 480,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // Delay so that we can see the window appear
    SDL_Delay(2000);

    // Cleanup and Quit
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone have an idea what's going on?

Comment: Check that your target architecture matches with libraries you've put to your `lib` directory.

Comment: @keltar didn't work